# Python: Get html data from a user based website

Tags: python, bots

I am very sorry for the horrendously worded question as I don't know how to phrase it differently. I am currently trying to make a bot play a game like skribbl or kahoot where you join, input a name and play. However I cannot just web-scrape the data with the join link as all the 's are empty and no new player joins. So how can I make a bot that joins the game. I don't necessarily need code. But I need resources to learn, I don't know what this kind of coding would be called.

Given I could just take screenshots frequently of my screen and try to go from there but I feel like it would be better to not do that and I want to expand my knowledge.

If this is not possible in python what other languages would be preferable?

Comment: Taking screenshots and doing image processing would be a fairly bonkers approach. The first thing that comes to mind here is something like WebDriver: navigate to this page, click here, fill out this text, read this field, etc.

Comment: if page uses JavaScript then you may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run JavaScript.

Comment: method with `screenshots` using python module `PyAutoGUI`: [Programming a Bot to Play the "Sushi Go Round" Flash Game - The Invent with Python Blog](https://inventwithpython.com/blog/2014/12/17/programming-a-bot-to-play-the-sushi-go-round-flash-game/)

Comment: Thank you everyone for responding this looks all really promising and I look forward to trying it all out. If there is still more stuff though I gladly will take all I can get